# Write a linear system in a new basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

thanks for spending some time helping :)

How exactly do you represent a linear system in a different basis?

Let's say the new basis B = {(1,1),(-1,1)}
How do I write the system
\begin{cases} x+y=7\\ 2x–4y=-16 \end{cases}
in the new basis?

Comment: What is the old basis? That is, how do you choose to represent your system of two equations so as to get an "old basis"? Once that is done, one can get a change of basis matrix from old to new or from new to old, whichever you wish.

Comment: They didn’t say, but I assume it is the canonical

Answer (score 0):

In terms of matrices your system is
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\2&-4\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}7\\-16\end{array}\right],$$
but if your basis change is
$$v_1=e_1+e_2,$$
$$v_2=-e_1+e_2,$$
then the old basis in terms of the new one is expressed as
$$e_1=\frac{1}{2}v_1-\frac{1}{2}v_2,$$
$$e_2=\frac{1}{2}v_1+\frac{1}{2}v_2.$$

The basis change associated matrix is
$B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&-1\\1&1\end{array}\right]$.

If the problem above can be written as
$Tu=w$
then by multiplying with $B^{-1}$ you will get the equivalent problem given by
$$(B^{-1}TB)B^{-1}u=B^{-1}w,$$
which is
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&-3\\-2&-3\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}\bar x\\\bar y\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c}-\frac{9}{2}\\-\frac{23}{2}\end{array}\right],$$
where the new variables are
$$\bar x=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y,$$
$$\bar y=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y.$$

So the system is
\begin{cases} 3\bar y=\frac{9}{2}\\ \\2\bar x+3\bar y=\frac{23}{2}\end{cases}

**Addendum**

The original problem's solution is
$u_0=\left[\begin{array}{c}2\\5\end{array}\right]$
and the transformed problem has the solution
$\left[\begin{array}{c}\frac{7}{2}\\\frac{3}{2}\end{array}\right]$, that perfectly coincides with $B^{-1}u_0$.

Comment: Matricially?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @mjw ok, I understand that isn't a common English word but is very transparent for what is talking here... have you an alternative construction to use?

Comment: $B^-1 * w$ = (-9/2, -23/2)? did'nt you misstype it?

Comment: @FernandoCavendish right!

Comment: Hahaha.  Saying it is not common is an understatement.  It's a word that has been used _once_ (unless you used it elsewhere).  Anyway, if you ask my opinion, either just delete the word, or if you have to say it, "Expressing your system in terms of  matrices ..."

Answer (score 0):

Any matrix multiplication is a projection over new basis, if you have:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\2&-4\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}7\\-16\end{array}\right],$$

and you want write it in new basis:
$$e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}, e_2=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
then multiply internally by new basis.
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&-4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}(\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}7\\-16\end{bmatrix}$$

where,
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\\\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}=e_1x+e_2y  \rightarrow new basis
$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\3&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\\\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7\\-16\end{bmatrix}$$

solution:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x}\\\hat{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/3&1/3\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}7\\-16\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\7\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which means, minus three times on $e_1$ and seven times on $e_2$

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you mean you have a new coordinate system, (x',y') where x'= x+ y and y'= -x+ y.  Adding the two equations, x'+ y'= 2y so y= (x'+ y')/2 and then x= x'- y= x'- (x'+ y')/2= x'/2- y'/2.

So x+ y= x'/2- y'/2+ x'/2+ y'/2= x'= 7 and
2x- 4y= 2(x'/2- y'/2)+ 4(x'/2+ y'/2)= x'- y'+ 2x'+ 2y'= 3x'- y'= -16.

The system of equations in this new basis is
x'= 7
3x'- y'= -16.